# Efficient way to get graph communities

Tags: r, graph, igraph

I have the following type of data where I know there will be lots of unconnected communities (good separation).  I want to efficiently (fast and preferably low/no dependencies) separate the data into their communities.  I know I can use **igraph** to do this task but was hoping there's a fast base R way to extract these communities.  I show how I separate the communities using I graph below.

***Is there a fast, base R way to extract communities?***  Sharing non-base R approaches is fine too so that this question is more useful to future searchers.

```
dat <-  data.frame(
    x = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'C',    'D', 'F',   'E',    'W', 'X', 'R', 'W'),
    y = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'C',    'F', 'F',   'E',    'Y', 'P', 'P', 'P')
)

mat <- xtabs(~ x + y, data = dat)

library(igraph)
g <- graph.data.frame(dat)
plot(g)

clust <- cluster_walktrap(g)

data.frame(
    val = clust$names,
    group = clust$membership
)
```

### Desired Output

```
##    val group
## 1    A     2
## 2    B     2
## 3    C     2
## 4    D     3
## 5    F     3
## 6    E     4
## 7    W     1
## 8    X     1
## 9    R     1
## 10   Y     1
## 11   P     1
```

[image]

Comment: You cannot deal with graphs in base R as fast as with igraph. Why are you opposed to igraph? Because of dependencies? Please define "fast".

Comment: @Roland I wanted to avoid the dependency but if that's the best solution then I'm fine with that.  This seems like a clustering/cooccurence problem  and I was thinking there's likely a matrix algrbra solution I'm overlooking. Fast would be relative to igraph.  If it's close/similar in speed or faster.  But fast in my mind is not precise, moreso relative.  I could of course use a for loop/while and look for indicies within rows and columns manually but that would be slow.

Comment: If there were another external package that was faster than igraph I'd be open to that to if I have to have the dependency anyway I'd want the fastest approach.

Comment: That would be off-topic. I don't expect there to be something faster than igraph. But it could be possible ...

Comment: @TylerRinker I agree with Roland that there's unlikely to be something faster than igraph, and probably not something as fast as igraph either. How much of a performance hit are you willing to take to avoid the dependency?

Comment: @TylerRinker, as it says in `?clusters`, for weakly connected components it uses a breadth-first search. Then as it says, e.g., in https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/56504/efficient-algorithm-for-finding-weakly-connected-components, there isn't a better algorithm asymptotically (for an individual graph, perhaps). Also note "any correct algorithm will have to examine every vertex and every edge at least once". So, everything boils down to implementations, and lines 89--162 in https://github.com/cran/igraph/blob/master/src/components.c look pretty concise.

Comment: ...That said, I also don't think one can come up with anything noticeably better.